# Soft Float Distro Raspberry Pi 2 for Java library file (.so)

Tags: java, eclipse, raspberry-pi, shared-libraries, raspbian

I am currently having a problem with importing/using a given library which is using soft float. As far as I know I can not use soft float libraries on hard float distros like the current Raspbian Stretch, which is why i am looking for a soft float version (currently the date of release does not matter).

The reason why I need this is that i get a error while running a java project in eclipse on my Pi2, although the file is there and *LD_LIBRARY_PATH* has been set.

***(java: error while loading shared libraries: mylibrary.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)***